# Open change DIV without refresh page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I extract this example code of a website to test it, the code have to show a text that if you click on it show you the code of test.php without refresh the page.

localhost/testing/index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#div-btn1').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.php",
        success: function(a) {
                $('#div-results').html(a);
        }
       });
   });
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="div-btn1" style="cursor:pointer;">Open file</a>

<div id="div-results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

localhost/testing/test.php

```
<?php echo "<p>Hello world</p>";?>
```

As you can see it´s a very simple code but I can´t do it works, I can see the content of index.php but when I click in "Open file" nothing occurs.

I'm working in a XAMPP server.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong there. What do you see when you look at the XHR request in the Net tab of your browser's developer tools?

Comment: try to check `alert(a)` instead of `.html(a)`. Do you have anything in popup?

Comment: A **good idea** would be to use current version of jquery. 1.4 is soo old...

Comment: @Tom, `.ajax` was added in 1.0 so it's not a problem

Comment: @vladkras Hmm if you're sure maybe it's something environmental then, code looks fine

Comment: I just want OP to add `error: function(xhr, status) { alert(xhr+' '+status); }` and show us result (if any)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've check your code on my local (ubuntu LAMP), just switched to current version of jquery like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

and it works :)

Comment: I'm very surprised, the problem was the version of jquery! I never would have thought.